# How do I incorporate sample size as a random variable in a latent interval censored model

Tags: r, bayesian, latent-variable, jags, interval-censoring

I've got a dataset wherein only every third success in a series of n trials is observed. I had originally used the following Bayesian model:

$$
y_i \sim \mathtt{floor}(z_i / 3) \\
z_i \sim B(n_i, p_z) \\
p_z \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)
$$

Where $y_i$ is the number of observed successes and $z_i$ is the latent count of all successes.

However, when considering my data, I realized that in most cases, the trials behaved like a negative binomial distribution and stopped as soon as $y_i$ was 1 but occasionally continued on (I'd estimate about 90% of the time it ends with the success, but the dataset doesn't include this information). After some thought I came up with the model:

$$
y_i \sim \mathtt{floor}(z_i / 3) \\
z_i = \begin{cases}
   w_i & w_i < 3 | w_i > 5 | u_i = 0 \\
   3 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
w_i \sim B(n^*_i, p_z) \\
u_i \sim B(1, p_u)\\
n^*_i \sim \text{Geo}(p_n) + 1 \\
n^u_i \sim \text{trunc}(\text{NB}(3, p_z), \text{upper} = \text{max}(n_i^* - 3, 0)) + 3\\
n_{obs} = \begin{cases}
   n_i^* & w_i < 3 | w_i > 5 | u_i = 0 \\
   n_i^u & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
p_z \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha_z, \beta_z) \\
p_u \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha_u, \beta_u) \\
p_n \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha_n, \beta_n)
$$

Where, as before, $y_i$ is the number of observed successes and $z_i$ is the latent count of all successes, but that there was some probability $p_u$ $(p_u = p(u_i = 1))$ that would cause trials to end abruptly in which case the number of trials wouldn't be the preallocated $n_i^*$ but the observed $n_i^u$ which is a shifted, truncated negative binomial random variable representing when the final success occured. The observed sample size, $n_{obs}$ would then be a random variable that would be the full preallocated $n_i^*$ unless $u_i = 1$ and $y_i = 1$.

I was feeling pretty clever until I realized I couldn't figure out the complete conditional for $u_i$ as it was now a dependency for $n_{obs}$ and I was in over my head. I tried to sidestep the issue with JAGS but I couldn't figure out how to reparameterize $n_{obs}$ so that it wasn't deterministic (as observed data has to be stochastic).

```jags
model {
    for(i in 1:N){
        y[i] ~ dinterval(z[i], breaks)
        z[i] <- ifelse(u[i] == 0 || w[i] < 3 || w[i] >= 6, w[i], 3)
        u[i] ~ dbern(p_u)
        n_star_fail[i] ~ dnegbin(p_n, 1)
        n_star[i] <- n_star_fail[i] + 1
        w[i] ~ dbin(p_z, n_star[i])
        n_u_fail[i] ~ dnegbin(p_z, 3)T(max(n_star[i] - 3, 0),)
        n_u[i] <- n_u_fail[i] + 3
        n_get[i] <- ifelse(u[i] == 0 || w[i] < 3 || w[i] >= 6, n_star[i], n_u[i])
        n[i] ~ dbin(1, n_get[i])
    }
    p_u ~ dbeta(1, 1)
    p_n ~ dbeta(1, 1)
    p_z ~ dbeta(1, 1)
}
```

```r
data <- list(
    breaks = c(2, 5, 8),
    y = dat_mod$drops,
    n = dat_mod$kills,
    N = 16249
)

inits <- list(
    p_u = rbeta(1, 1, 1),
    p_n = rbeta(1, 1, 1),
    p_w = rbeta(1, 1, 1)
)

params <- c("p_u", "p_n", "p_w")

jags.model("ring.jags", data, inits)
```

How can I model this? Do I need to rethink what I've done or is there a math trick that would make this simpler?

Dataset can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iAqZm-SByFPsTjDTZbVC5ZdYrkrqbvbGyKZbLI0Ac-Q/edit?usp=sharing). For context it's the kill and drop rates for some new items in Old School RuneScape with an interesting drop mechanic I was hoping to learn more about. Data was scraped from collectionlog.net such that the players included were sampled [mostly] independently of whether or not they recieved the drop. Most players stop killing bosses once they get the drop so it has presented quite the modeling conundrum.